# Build error after updating from Angular 9 to Angular 10: "ERROR in Can't bind to 'selectedValue' since it isn't a known property of 'tbody'"

Tags: angular, date, angular-material, build-error

I just upgraded from Angular 9.1 to 10 and I'm getting the below error:

```
ERROR in Can't bind to 'selectedValue' since it isn't a known property of 'tbody'. ("
[rows]="_weeks"
[todayValue]="_todayDate!"
[ERROR ->][selectedValue]="_selectedDate!"
[labelMinRequiredCells]="3"
[activeCell]="_dateA")
```

There is no reference to which file/package/bundle the error is originating from so it's difficult to debug. And... there are no compile errors (ng serve) or warnings.

I am using Angular Material 10.1.3, cdk 10.1.3, ngx-material-timepicker: 5.5.2

Things I've tried and didn't work:
Adding CommonModule to all of my child modules.
Checking for template errors on Tables with dates.
Searched entire app for key words in the error message like "selectedValue", "_selectedDate!"...etc.
Deleted node modules and reinstall npm.
Hours of research trying to find an answer.

Comment: It sounds like it is related to a calendar, you can't have too many date/calendar tools in your app can you? Comment them out until you find the one with the problem.. Also try `npm audit` just in case it finds something.

Comment: @Steve I'm pretty certain it has to do with a mat-calendar class inside datepicker.   I'm no expert, but I think the month view for datepicker is a <table> with a <tbody> and the issue is with the attributes inside that <tbody>.  Could this be a Material datepicker bug? I've checked my datepickers (I have a lot)  and they all seem to be working.  Oh, and I did run npm audit, nothing significant there unfortunately. My next step may be to revert back to Angular 9.1.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed my build by manually uninstalling @angular-material-components/datetime-picker and reinstalling, version 4.0.5.